# View trash sorted by date deleted

Tags: macos, trash

I was trying to organize and select all my old music from my previous computer and copied a folder with all my music files to my mac book desktop. Started deleting all the songs I didn't wanted and after all done, accidentally I selected all the music that was left on the folder and deleted it as well. Is there is a way I can access the trash and see only the latest music files I deleted? If I could see the time they where deleted I knew which music files I have to restore, so I don't have to be restoring all the files, including the ones I do not want!

Comment: you want to see when the Trash was last emptied?

Answer (score 12):

Too late now, but next time you accidentally move/delete something in the Finder, remember  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  is the (almost) universal shortcut for Undo.

For now, open the Trash, set to List View, then right click the columns bar & add "Date Added". Then click that to sort latest additions to the top.

[image]